# EntityFramework Code First FluentAPI TPC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, fluent-interface, table-per-class

**Here there are my domain entities**:

```
public class Province
{
    private ICollection<City> _cities;

    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities
    {
        get { return _cities ?? (_cities = new HashSet<City>()); }
        set { _cities = value; }
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual double Latitude { get; set; }
    public virtual double Longitude { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    private Province _province;

    public virtual Province Province
    {
        get { return _province ?? (_province = new Province()); }
        set { _province = value; }
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Latitude { get; set; }
    public virtual string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

**Mappings**:

```
public class ProvinceMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Province>
{
    public ProvinceMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Province");

        this.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.Latitude).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.Longitude).IsRequired();

        //this.HasMany(x => x.Cities)
        //    .WithRequired(x => x.Province)
        //    .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}

public class CityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<City>
{
    public CityMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("City");

        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.Latitude).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.Longitude).IsRequired();

        this.HasRequired(x => x.Province)
            .WithMany(x => x.Cities)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

**Context**:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(): base("DataContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, Configuration>("DataContext"));
    }

    public DbSet<Province> Provinces { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProvinceMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CityMap());
        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I run the 'update-database' command at the Nuget Package Console, I have an error:

Invalid multiplicity in the element Role "City_Province_Source" in connection "City_Province". Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity properties Dependent Role must be equal to "1".

Comment: I read them, but my case is different, unlike other. I've tried offered solutions, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logically, you are trying to define a 1-to-many relationship. Because `City` cannot be in many `Provinces`, and one `Province` can have many `Cities`.

In this case, you don't necessarily need to specify `HasRequired` and `WithMany` in your mapping.

Remove the following code from `CityMap`

```
this.HasRequired(x => x.Province)
        .WithMany(x => x.Cities)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id);
```

Having `ICollection<City>` in `Province` table, and a property type of `Province` in `City` table is enough to establish the relationship.

The output will be like this.

[image]